# Interpreting Hardware Error Messages

Tags: linux-kernel

I am running Debian 11 with an AMD Ryzen CPU.

From time to time I get Hardware Error messages from the kernel such as :-

Message from syslogd@piglit at Oct 25 12:52:37 ...
kernel:[239393.673321] [Hardware Error]: Corrected error, no action
required.

Message from syslogd@piglit at Oct 25 12:52:37 ...
kernel:[239393.673325] [Hardware Error]: CPU:1 (19:21:2)
MC25_STATUS[-|CE|MiscV|-|PCC|-|CECC|-|-|Scrub]: 0x8b48c789480043a7

Message from syslogd@piglit at Oct 25 12:52:37 ...
kernel:[239393.673329] [Hardware Error]: IPID: 0x0000000000000000

Message from syslogd@piglit at Oct 25 12:52:37 ...
kernel:[239393.673330] [Hardware Error]: Platform Security Processor
Ext. Error Code: 0, High SRAM ECC or parity error.

Message from syslogd@piglit at Oct 25 12:52:37 ...
kernel:[239393.673332] [Hardware Error]: cache level: L3/GEN, tx: DATA
[12874:12874:1025/173910.926147:ERROR:interface_endpoint_client.cc(696)]
Message 0 rejected by interface blink.mojom.WidgetHost

Is anyone able to interpret what the above messages mean or can they direct me to somewhere where I can get help with the
above ?

Answer (score 0):

The messages mean that a memory error was detected and corrected. As indicated in the first message, you don’t need to do anything:

> Corrected error, no action required.

However if similar errors occur frequently, your memory may need replacing. You can test it using a tool such as [Memtest86+](https://memtest.org/).